# How do I change user to uid/gid 760?

Tags: users

I requested creation of new user (so that all processes by particular program could be owned by this user). Our admin told me that this new user has uid/gid 760.

Please, how do I switch to this user?

Comment: You need the USERNAME.  That's the first part (up to the first colon) of the `getent` output.

Answer (score 4):

Your admin could have given you the name of the user, but it's easy to establish.

Print the passwd entry for userid 760

```
getent passwd 760
```

I get this (my userid is 1000) :

```
xtian:x:1000:1000:xtian,,,:/home/xtian:/bin/bash
```

The username is the first field (: is delimiter) the numerical id and group are columns 3 and 4 read more with `man 5 passwd`

Maybe admin has not assigned a password to that account ? So try,

```
su username
```

If you require a password then you need to ask admin to set it and let you know what it is, so you can su to that user.

Comment: That's an awesome answer, but I am geeting empty string after typing "getent passwd 760". So I suppose that this has not been set correctly:/

Comment: Yes. As an extra check you could try following command `grep 760 /etc/passwd` , but maybe your server authenticates using another method than the password file, which is also a possibility.